# How to attribution values of javascript arraylist to java arraylist in the same html page

Tags: javascript, java

I have a javascript `Arraylist` like this:

```
var javaScriptArray = $('#sortable').sortable("toArray"); // array of sortable elements
```

And I want to send this javascript `Arraylist` to java arrayList in the same `jsp` page

```
<% List <String> javaList ;
   javaList = javaScriptArray;
%>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: JavaScript is client side, jsp is server side. To get information from JS to jsp, you need to send it to the server and rerender the page.

Comment: so can I send this JS arrayList to java controller and deal with it there ?

Comment: I don't know jsp, but I assume so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it in a wrong way. As I have understand from your description `and I want to send this javascript Arraylist to java arrayList in the same jsp page` you want to pass a value from javascript directly to your jsp variable that is on the same page.

Always remember, JSP(JSF, other)/Pearl/Python/PHP and a like were server script(Server side) while Javascript is a client script(Client side).

This mean that you can pass the value from the server script to client script(Not a good practice) BEFORE the response/page were rendered to the client using `<%= "Hello" %>` or similar. But you CANNOT pass the value from the client to server which have ALREADY rendered the page to the client where the server is not aware of what is happening on the client.

It is like, when you order pizza from phone, the one that does the packing knows exactly what are on the box. But He/she will not know what will be added to it once it reaches you(the one who ordered it).

And to address your problem of passing of value from client to server. You have to pass the value from client to server using GET, POST, and other HTTP methods. This way, the server will be notified that the value of JavaScript changed. This is only good in passing value to notify the server to save/update/delete a record from the server.

This image will be helpful on how Client/Server interact to each other.
[image]